# Access API Linkedin with B2C user

Tags: asp.net, api, linkedin-api, azure-ad-b2c

I have created a B2C tenant with an user flow that contain a linkedin way for connect.
In my ASP.NET website, i want to display linkedin's informations of the user connected.

In my research, i have seen different way to make this but it is possible only with custom policy and i need to know if in 2020, there is a solution or not, to get user info by linkedin.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like [passing an access token through a user flow to your application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/idp-pass-through-user-flow) can be useful. With the access token the application will be able to call the LinkedIn API directly.

Comment: thanks for you're answer ! but in the microsoft's exemple, they use jwt.ms for get the token. Can i make a jwt call in my code for get the idp_access_token or there are others way to get this ?

Comment: The idp token is returned in the id_token that AAD B2C issues to your App - jwt.ms is sample app. Your app then needs to parse the id_token claims to find the id_access_token. It can then use this claim value (essentially an embedded JWT) to call the Linekdin API.